R script to count keywords in a PDF?
I have a number of pdf files and I need to search each of them for particular key words/phrases. For each pdf, I want to know how many of these key words/phrases appear (but not how many times they appear). For each key word/phrase that appears, I want to assign one point (no matter how many times it appears). For each that doesn't, zero points. I would like a script that can scan pdfs and count key words/phrases in the above way. I've looked at the readPDF function and the PDF Data Extractor (PDE), and have created code with advice I received from a previous question. Here is the code:
# set the current script's location as working directory
setwd('/Users/steve/OneDrive/Desktop')

#install.packages(c("pdftools", "stringr", "dplyr"))
library(pdftools)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

## Define the list of keywords/phrases here #########
keywords <- c("keyword1", "keywordn")

# Function to count keywords in a PDF
count_keywords <- function(file = "C:\\Users\\steve\
\OneDrive\Desktop\\CL\\156.pdf", keywords) {
return(data.frame(
PDF = basename("C:\\Users\\steve\\OneDrive\\Desktop\
\CL\\156.pdf"),
Keyword = keywords,
One_if_found = sapply(keywords, function(keyword) { 
as.numeric(str_detect(paste(pdf_text("C:\\Users\\steve\\OneDrive\
\Desktop\\CL\\156.pdf"), collapse = " "),
fixed(keywords, ignore_case = TRUE))) })
))
}

# Directory containing PDF files # create a folder on the same   
#level as this script called "pdfs" and store your pdfs there
pdf_dir <- "CL"

# Combine results into a single data frame
final_results <- bind_rows(lapply(list.files(pdf_dir, pattern = "
\.pdf$", full.names = TRUE), count_keywords, keywords = keywords))

print(final_results)# Print the results

The result I get is a very large dataframe with a row for each instance a keyword appears (not whether or not it appears), and columns for each keyword, whose values are all the same across the row, like this:
PDF     Keyword     One_if_found.keyword1    One_if_found.keywordn    ...
156.pdf keyword1    1                        1
156.pdf keywordn    0                        0
156.pdf keyword1    1                        1
156.pdf keywordn    0                        0
...

I'd like to have a dataframe with just three columns: the PDF name, the keyword, and whether the keyword appears in the PDF (1) or not (2). How can I change my code to do this?

Your question is likely to be closed because you have not provided any evidence that you tried writing any code first.

Your error is, that you hardcoded this PDF = basename("C:\\Users\\steve\\OneDrive\\Desktop\ \CL\\156.pdf") in my function, instead of using basename(pdf_path) where pdf_path is the function argument. Or in your case, it should be basename(file) since you changed the function argument name. You should not give your function a specific default value with function(file = "C:\\Users\\steve\ \OneDrive\Desktop\\CL\\156.pdf", keywords)

You can use the pdftools package to extract text from PDFs and then search for keywords/phrases.

you have to create a folder in the same place as the r-script: "pdf_dir <- "pdfs" and place your pdfs in there!
Also specify your keywords in keywords

Adding to my previous response.
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path)) # set the current script's location as working directory
#install.packages(c("pdftools", "stringr", "dplyr"))
library(pdftools)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

## Define the list of keywords/phrases here
keywords <- c("information", "hairsser", "example phrase")

# Function to count keywords in a PDF
count_keywords <- function(pdf_path, keywords) {
  # this function checks if the words in "keywords" are present in the pdf file with path "pdf_path". 
  # Returns data frame:
  # the name of the pdf    | the keyword      |1 if found, 2 if not
  # PDF_name                Keyword            Found
  # 1 somatosensory - 2.pdf    information     1
  # 2 somatosensory - 2.pdf       hairsser     2
  # 3 somatosensory - 2.pdf example phrase     2
  # Args:
  # pdf_path: the path to the pdf files which should be checked for keywords
  # the vector containing the keywords: e.g. "c("information", "hairsser", "example phrase")"
  return(
    data.frame(
      PDF_name = basename(pdf_path),
      Keyword = keywords,
      Found = sapply(keywords, function(keyword) {
        if_else(
          str_detect( paste(pdf_text(pdf_path), collapse = " "),fixed(keyword, ignore_case = TRUE)),
          1, # one if true  -> string detected
          2  # two if false -> string NOT detected
        )
      })
    ,row.names = NULL)
  )
}

# Check all pdf files stored in one directory "pdf_dir"
# Directory containing PDF files # create a folder on the same level as this script called "pdfs" and store your pdfs there
pdf_dir <- "pdfs"
pdf_files <- list.files(pdf_dir, pattern = "\\.pdf$", full.names = TRUE)
# This iterates over all pdfs files in "pdf_files" and adds the results together using bind_rows
final_results <- bind_rows(lapply(pdf_files, count_keywords, keywords = keywords))
print(final_results)# Print the results

Which results in
> print(final_results)# Print the results
               PDF_name        Keyword Found
1 somatosensory - 2.pdf    information     1
2 somatosensory - 2.pdf       hairsser     2
3 somatosensory - 2.pdf example phrase     2
4     somatosensory.pdf    information     1
5     somatosensory.pdf       hairsser     2
6     somatosensory.pdf example phrase     2

Or use the function count_keywords only on one pdf
# Or use "count_keywords" to check only one pdf
# - "pdfs/somatosensory - 2.pdf" is the RELATIVE path to the pdf file going out from this script
# this script
# pdfs 
#   |_somatosensory - 2.pdf
count_keywords("pdfs/somatosensory - 2.pdf", keywords = keywords)

which results in:
               PDF_name        Keyword Found
1 somatosensory - 2.pdf    information     1
2 somatosensory - 2.pdf       hairsser     2
3 somatosensory - 2.pdf example phrase     2

or for your example:
one_pdf_result <- count_keywords("C:\\Users\\steve\\OneDrive\Desktop\\CL\\156.pdf", keywords = c("keyword1", "keywordn"))


how about  keyword_found <- sapply(keywords, function(keyword) {     as.numeric(str_detect(full_text, fixed(keyword, ignore_case = TRUE)))) }  ?
